# Imploding in PHP an array from Json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
"num_found": 407343,
"results": [
    {
        "speaker_state": "LA",
        "speaking": [
            "ABC",
            "DEF",
            "GHI"
        ],
        "speaker_party": "D",
    },
```

And so on. I am trying to parse this data into a MySQL database. I adapted the following php code:

```
<?php

$hostname_ndb = "localhost";
$database_ndb = "senate";
$username_ndb = "root";
$password_ndb = "root";
$ndb = mysql_pconnect($hostname_ndb, $username_ndb, $password_ndb) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_ndb);

$url = "http://xxx.yyy/text.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$out = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($out["results"] as $results) { 
$speaker_state = $results['speaker_state']; 
$speaking2 = $results['speaking'];
$speaking = implode('', $speaking2);
$date = $results['date'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO speeches (speaker_state, speaking, date ) VALUES('$speaker_state', '$speaking','$date')") or die (mysql_error()); 

}

?>
```

There is an array within an array and it seems to be the problem. The script does not work, data is not stored in the database. The script returns the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'speaking, date, ' at line 1.

The PHP log shows a notice:"PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/json.php on line 46" in the php log.

var_dump($speaking2) returns:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(713) "XXX" [1]=> string(891) "ZZZ" [2]=> string(1189)
```

and so on.
How would you advise me to adapt this script to make it work?

Comment: 1. It's a notice, not an error 2. What shows `var_dump($speaking2)`

Comment: I updated my question with more information.

Comment: off topic, but please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated and their use is discouraged. You should consider switching to a better supported database API such as the PDO library.

Comment: `echo` your query's text and see what's wrong in it. Try to perform this query in phpmyadmin, for example.

Comment: I am not sure how to echo a query. Newbie here.

Comment: @user1029296 - before proceeding any further with your program, you should read the following: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and [How to write DB code using the PDO library instead of the mysql functions](http://www.sitepoint.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'speaking, date, ' at line 1.

The reason for this error is that you are using `date` as a field name.

`date` is a reserved word in SQL, and will thus cause an error if you use it as a field name or table name.

Ideally you should not use SQL reserved words in your DB table or field names, but if you do, you need to wrap the names in back-ticks so that mySQL will accept them. (in fact, it's generally recommended good practice to do this to all field names and table names; not compulsory, but good practice)

So your query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `speeches` (`speaker_state`, `speaking`, `date`) VALUES ('$speaker_state', '$speaking','$date')
```

I would also note that you don't seem to be escaping your input data. You should use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape any variables that you put into your query (ie `$speaker_state`, `$speaking` and `$date`). Failure to do this can result in errors and in your site being vulnerable to being hacked.

(note also that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated; ideally you should be using a different set of database functions, in which case there would be a different method for escaping the variables, but as things stand you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`)

> PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/json.php on line 46

This is entirely un-related to the mySQL error. It may still be a problem that may still need to be looked into, but it isn't the cause of the SQL error that you're asking about.

I can't be certain without knowing which line is line 46, but what is probably happening here is that the incoming JSON string produces an array for one of the three variables that you are putting into your SQL string. You're treating them as strings, but one of them isn't a string. This will probably cause data corruption, so you should look into it. I can't tell anything more than that without seeing the actual JSON string, but you should use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to examine the contents of the variables.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I added the back brackets. Now the error is: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's health, extended access to higher education, the concerns of our Nation's vete' at line 1" which is a piece of the text that is part of the variable "speaking." Are you sure that the fact that "speaking" is an array is not a problem in the MySQL query?

Comment: @user1029296. If you're getting a MySQL error within what should be *content*, that's further evidence that you're not escaping stuff correctly. You should be doing that. (`mysql_real_escape_string` or (better) `mysqli_real_escape_string` is your friend here.)

Comment: The reason for this next error is because you haven't followed my advice about escaping the input variables. The text contains a quote character, and **must** be escaped.

Comment: @TRiG - the choice of escape function is dictated by the choice of DB function he's using for the query, etc. You can't mix and match. (well, I guess you can, but it's not a good idea). Ideally he should switch to using a better database API, but I get the feeling that it may be a struggle to get him to switch.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I was just trying to reiterate your advice to move away from the `mysql_*` functions to the `mysqli_*` functions, but my writing wasn't as clear as it should have been. @user1029296. `mysqli_*` is, generally speaking, better, and the `mysql_*` functions are depricated and will soon be removed.

Comment: Ok I just did what you suggested for all variables. Now, for example "$speaking = implode('', $speaking2);" is replacedwith "$speaking = mysql_real_escape_string(implode('', $speaking2));". It seems to load fine in the database, except for the "speaking" column where cells are empty.

Comment: @user1029296 - glad it works. Please read the links I posted in the comment on the question above before going too much further. Since you're a newbie, I strongly recommend switching to the PDO library now before you get stuck with too much code using the old mysql functions.